# Does $.post means partial postback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

When we use $.post, I used breakpoint and found that my Page_Load event fires again.
So what is the use of $.post, is this a partial postback?

I am confused, if Page_Load event fires in both cases (server side call, $.post)
then what are the advantages of $.post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are using $.post to access the same page, which completely defeats the purpose of using ajax. You should $.post either to a webservice (or another page) that directly handles your request.

Also, to address your main question, $.post is not technically a postback at all. It is an xmlHttpRequest (ajax). The term "partial postback" generally refers to ajax.

Comment: Yes you are right. Many of developers are using $.post to access data/html for same page.
Can you please elaborate more like best time to use $.post?

Comment: If you add a comment here or upvote me, would you prefer if the page completely refreshes or silently executes an xmlHttpRequest in the background and modifies the page with javascript? It is up to you, the developer, to decide when it's awesome to use ajax.

Comment: ok great to see your comments, we can decide when to use $.post so that our purpose can be fulfill without page refresh. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) issues an [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request to the server without submitting the page's `<form>`. Neither partial nor complete postback occurs.

But if you request the URL to your page that way, it will indeed be served and its `Page_Load` handler will run.

If you're trying to invoke a page method, chances are you will have to change the `dataType` you specify (or decorate your page method with the [[WebMethod]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) attribute if you forgot to do so).

Comment: Dear Frederic,
Can you please elaborate some more in detail ?

Comment: @Gaurav, well, `$.post()` allows you to perform an HTTP `POST` request and access the resulting data (the same thing your browser does when submitting a form). It can be used to fetch page fragments or even full pages, but also (and probably more often) to obtain non-markup data from web services. It gets complicated because ASP.NET pages can *also* be used as web services (with the aforementioned web methods).

Answer (score 0):

$.post has pne best advantage:
User didn't know whether the page refreshed or not.
He will able to see the data without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally webpages required reloading to update their content. For web-based email this meant that users had to manually reload their inbox to check and see if they had new mail. This had huge drawbacks: it was slow and it required user input. When the user reloaded their inbox, the server had to reconstruct the entire web page and resend all of the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, as well as the user's email. This was hugely inefficient. Ideally, the server should only have to send the user's new messages, not the entire page. By 2003 all the major browsers, solved this issue by adopting the XMLHttpRequest (XHR) object, allowing browsers to communicate with the server without requiring a page reload.

The XMLHttpRequest object is part of a technology called Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Using Ajax, data could then be passed between the browser and the server, using the XMLHttpRequest API, without having to reload the web page. With the widespread adoption of the XMLHttpRequest object it quickly became possible to build web applications like Google Maps, and GMail that used XMLHttpRequest to get new map tiles, or new email without having to reload the entire page.

Ajax requests are triggered by JavaScript code; your code sends a request to a URL, and when it receives a response, a callback function can be triggered to handle the response. Because the request is asynchronous, the rest of your code continues to execute while the request is being processed, so it’s imperative that a callback be used to handle the response.

Unfortunately, different browsers implement the Ajax API differently. Typically this meant that developers would have to account for all the different browsers to ensure that Ajax would work universally. Fortunately, jQuery provides Ajax support that abstracts away painful browser differences. It offers both a full-featured $.ajax() method, and simple convenience methods such as $.get(), $.getScript(), $.getJSON(), $.post(), and $().load().

Most jQuery applications don’t in fact use XML, despite the name “Ajax”; instead, they transport data as plain HTML or JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).

In general, Ajax does not work across domains. For instance, a webpage loaded from example1.com is unable to make an Ajax request to example2.com as it would violate the same origin policy. As a work around, JSONP (JSON with Padding) uses  tags to load files containing arbitrary JavaScript content and JSON, from another domain. More recently browsers have implemented a technology called Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), that allows Ajax requests to different domains.

Key Concepts

Proper use of Ajax-related jQuery methods requires understanding some key concepts first.

GET vs. Post

The two most common “methods” for sending a request to a server are GET and POST. It’s important to understand the proper application of each.

The GET method should be used for non-destructive operations — that is, operations where you are only “getting” data from the server, not changing data on the server. For example, a query to a search service might be a GET request. GET requests may be cached by the browser, which can lead to unpredictable behavior if you are not expecting it. GET requests generally send all of their data in a query string.

The POST method should be used for destructive operations — that is, operations where you are changing data on the server. For example, a user saving a blog post should be a POST request. POST requests are generally not cached by the browser; a query string can be part of the URL, but the data tends to be sent separately as post data.

Data Types

jQuery generally requires some instruction as to the type of data you expect to get back from an Ajax request; in some cases the data type is specified by the method name, and in other cases it is provided as part of a configuration object. There are several options:

text

For transporting simple strings

html

For transporting blocks of HTML to be placed on the page

script

For adding a new script to the page

json

For transporting JSON-formatted data, which can include strings, arrays, and objects

Note

As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON data sent by your server isn't properly formatted, the request may fail silently. See http://json.org for details on properly formatting JSON, but as a general rule, use built-in language methods for generating JSON on the server to avoid syntax issues.

jsonp

For transporting JSON data from another domain

xml

For transporting data in a custom XML schema

I am a strong proponent of using the JSON format in most cases, as it provides the most flexibility. It is especially useful for sending both HTML and data at the same time.

A is for Asynchronous

The asynchronicity of Ajax catches many new jQuery users off guard. Because Ajax calls are asynchronous by default, the response is not immediately available. Responses can only be handled using a callback. So, for example, the following code will not work:

123456789 
var response; $.get( "foo.php", function( r ) {   response = r; }); console.log( response ); // undefined

Instead, we need to pass a callback function to our request; this callback will run when the request succeeds, at which point we can access the data that it returned, if any.

123 
$.get( "foo.php", function( response ) {  console.log( response ); // server response});

Same-Origin Policy and JSONP

In general, Ajax requests are limited to the same protocol (http or https), the same port, and the same domain as the page making the request. This limitation does not apply to scripts that are loaded via jQuery's Ajax methods.

The other exception is requests targeted at a JSONP service on another domain. In the case of JSONP, the provider of the service has agreed to respond to your request with a script that can be loaded into the page using a  tag, thus avoiding the same-origin limitation; that script will include the data you requested, wrapped in a callback function you provide